# what is the truth table for this logic statement?

Tags: logic, truthtable

p∨q

p →∼ q

p → r

∴ r

I need to construct a truth table for this but am not sure if this is correct any help is appreciated

[image]

Comment: How is this question related to programming? Do you need to deduce the formula for `R` in runtime based on dynamically input truth table from `P, Q, R`? Also, consider adding [truthtable](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/truthtable/info) tag and perhaps removing [logic](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/logic/info) tag as irrelevant to your question.

Comment: we are being asked to manually work out the logic equations for logic programming

Comment: If it is not about writing code, then [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/) and [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) may be a better place to ask (I am not sure, check their on-topic lists before posting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I got. The `A -> B` ones I switched to `!A v B` to make the values a little easier to figure out since `A -> B = !A v B`.

[image: truth table]